# Using forms with models

Tags: python, django, forms, model

How would I display form based on models when I am using `composition` with them? As an example

```
class House(models.Model):
    number_of_roommates = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Posting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    house = models.OneToOneField(House)
```

I am stumped on what the view should be like. Right now I have two form classes for each of the Models.

```
def form_view(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        Post = Posting(request.POST) ##Not really sure what to do here
        house = House(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('co_op.views.list_view')
    else:
        descriptionForm = PostDescription()
        houseForm = HouseDescription()
    return render(request, 'co_op/form_view.html', { 
                                                    'descForm' : descriptionForm, 'houseForm' : houseForm,})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [django Modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) for this.

By calling your models classes by PostDescription() etc , you are just creating objects of those classes, not forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about how forms work in Django.Apart from the documentation,please go through http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/forms.html is much more easier to understand and execute what you want.For beginners , I think this is much more helpful than the actual docs.